# Is there a specific Exception for the API4 like CiviCRM_API3_Exception?

Tags: api, errorhandling

There is a specific Exception for the CiviCRM API3 called CiviCRM_API3_Exception. Is there a similar specific Exception for API4 or do I just catch the standard Exception?

Answer (score 3):

I believe api4 throws API_Exception and sometimes Exception.

Comment: Agree, e.g. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.21.0/Civi/Api4/Generic/Result.php#L85